# Стоимость, по которой ресторан приобретает ингридиенты

Tags: названия

Какое название имеет подлинная стоимость ингридиентов пиццы в ресторане (в некоторых пиццериях в меню содержатся указания на "розничную" цену ингридиентов, если вы желаете самостоятельно ее "собрать" или чем-нибудь приправить)? Себестоимость, оптовая цена?

Comment: Владимир, сколько уже раз просил давать контекст!!!

Answer (score 0):

Розничные цены - цены, по которым товары и услуги реализуются населению. (не подходит)

Оптовая цена - цена со скидкой на товар, покупаемый в большом количестве. (не подходит)

Однозначно это **себестоимость**. Это понятие обозначает именно стоимость ингредиентов.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я именно так хочу - как сноска после предложения. А в предложение нельзя ставить, если комментарий относится ко всему предложению, а не к его части.

Comment: @Владимир Это называется "себестоимость ингредиентов". А в себестоимость пиццы уже входят все затраты.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему ко всему не может относиться. :)

Comment: Потому что это продолжение мысли. Тогда уже лучше оформлять как новое полноценное предложение. Ну и логически... Описываем всё предложение. Точка тоже к нему относится. Тогда правильнее комментировать после точки. И желательно сделать отступ или каким-то знаком отделить комментарий, или шрифтом. Чтобы вообще не казалось, что это продолжение предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Это надо у авторов сего уродца спросить. 
Наука такого зверя как "розничная стоимость" не знает, есть розничная цена.

Могу только предположить, что это вообще не имеет отношения к ценам, по которой продукты покупаются - это скорее всего про то, что в нормальных местах называется "дополнительно". То есть то, что добавляется (в пиццу в нашем случае) сверх обычной рецептуры - вот на такие добавки заведение и устанавлиывает свои цены, которые чья-то умная голова назвала "розничными".

> Стоимость, по которой ресторан приобретает ингридиенты

А вот этот вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к основному тексту. 
Ресторан, как и любое другое предприятие, может приобретать по розничным ценам, может по оптовым, может по договорным, может по рыночным. Называется это "цена закупки", впрочем сам термин малоупотребим, ибо не несет функциональной нагрузки.
В любом случае все это закладывается в себестоимость изделия/продукта.

Я бы уточнил у знающих, но к сожалению ваши формулировки не позволяет этого сделать. Вы началали за здравие - кончили за упокой.

Comment: Почему отношения не имеет? Как в названии вопроса, так и в содержании речь идет о наименовании стоимости компонентов пиццы. А разве при употреблении термина "себестоимость" не возникает представление о всех затратах (на персонал, на оборудование)? "Себестоимость ингридиентов" не включает в себя стоимость их обработки, найма поваров и так далее?

Comment: @Владимир потому что ваши "представления" не предмет для рассмотрения на этом ресурсе. Заголовок вопроса должен быть четким, понятным и передавать суть самого вопроса. Смотрите правила.  --- А у вас вообще "в огороде бузина, а в Киеве дядька." Вы не ращобравшись с термином "розничная цена", противопоставили его оптовой, смысла которой тоже не понимает.

Answer (score 0):

**Оптовая цена** - цена со скидкой на повышенное количество закупаемого.

**Себестоимость** - затраты продавца на производство *и реализацию* товара. По цене себестоимости (или более низкой цене, в убыток) продают что-либо *только* в случае, когда продавец заинтересован в скорейшем избавлении от товара.

**Розничная цена** (или *стоимость при продаже в розницу* - для массового покупателя, клиента) - цена для *единицы* (или малого количества) товара, устанавливаемая для конкретного места или условий продажи. В вашем случае эта цена **заведомо выше** как себестоимости, так и оптовой цены. У заведения есть основания употребить прилагательное *розничный*. *Розничная стоимость* (вместо "цены") - не вполне естественное выражение.

Таким образом, можно сказать, что ингредиенты ресторан *приобретает по оптовым ценам* и может устанавливать *различные* ***розничные цены*** на ингредиенты в стандартно приготовленном продукте (если для стандартного варианта блюда клиентам тоже указывается цена отдельных ингредиентов) и на ингредиенты, выбранные клиентом для заказного варианта блюда.

Comment: Эти цены на компоненты **не называются** "розничными". И уж тем более не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу о том, по каким ценам ресторан **приобретает** товар.

Comment: *приобретает по оптовым ценам* - хороший ресторан приобретает может приобретать всё у частника, который вообще таких слов как оптовая цена не знает. Эти цены называются ценой закупки - они могут быть розничными, оптовыми, индивидуальными - это уж как карта ляжет.

Comment: *У заведения есть основания употребить прилагательное розничный.* - вместо "отпускной цены"?! Ну-ну...

Comment: Я же не говорю, что все рестораны всегда покупают по оптовым ценам и всегда употреблют слово "розничный". Вопрос был о том, насколько корректно в меню выражение с этим прилагательным (+ по каким ценам ресторан это покупает), степень корректности имеющегося я и оцениваю. Остальное - как точнее или понятнее ресторатору это называть и какая на этот счёт сложилась массовая практика.

Comment: *Вопрос был о том, насколько корректно в меню выражение* - Я могу убедиться, что вопрос именно об этом?! Как-то совсем не просматривается такая постановка вопроса. *Остальное - как точнее или понятнее ресторатору это называть* - гениальный совет. ))) И главное годится почти на все вопросы от Владимира. Ресторатору виднее как называть цены, дворнику - как называть метлу, филологу  тут делать нечего.

Comment: Да, действительно, вопрос состоял не в выяснении корректности сочетания "розничная цена" ингридиентов в меню, а в выяснении наименования ее "цены закупки".

Comment: *а в выяснении наименования ее* - кого её? "цены закупки розничной цены"?! Я пас... Спасибо.

Comment: Их - ингридиентов (ясно же). Зачем буквоедство...